# ModelState Error is not getting removed after refresh the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using a general login view. Say, I entered invalid credentials, model is returned with error from controller. When I try to refresh page its not refreshing View.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing a refresh or a full page reload?

My guess is you're refreshing which is re-posting the form and values which would cause the same ModelState errors to be present.

Try visiting the page again by copy and pasting the url back into the browser or navigating away from your login page and revisiting

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. Refreshing after a POST sends the POST request again.